# C++ size_t in mixed arithmetic and logical operations

Tags: c++, type-conversion, size-t

Currently using WSL2, g++, with `-std=c++20 -Wall -Wextra -Wvla -Weffc++ -Wsign-conversion -Werror`.

In the program I'm building, because I utilize several STL containers such as `std::vector`, `std::array`, `std::string`, etc, I've come across many situations involving integer arithmetic or logical comparisons between `size_t` (from `.size()` or `.length()`) and signed values.

To avoid errors from occuring, I have changed values (that "I think" should generally always be positive) into unsigned values, either by changing the variable definition, or using `static_cast<size_t>()` (which make my code lines especially long). But now I'm encountering more and more underflow errors.

Should I change all the variables back to signed types and use assertions to see if they go negative? What are some efficient ways to conduct integer arithmetic and logical comparisons between signed integers and unsigned integers (especially from `.size()`)?

Comment: Post a case where you _think_ you need to change to a common type.  The solution may lie in not forcing the common type.

Comment: Example: To compare `int < size_t`, could use  `int_var < 0 || (unsigned) int_var < size_var` --> No loss of information.  Valid for every possible `int, size_t` pair.

Comment: Are those situations loops traversing containers? Consider using [algorithms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) instead. Since C++20 you can also use "safe" comparisons: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/intcmp

Comment: There cannot be that many signed integers being compared to or being added to a size() in a program.  If there are so many of them, then there is a design issue.  In modern c++ , you must learn to identify and work wiith unsigned variables, and use variables of type size_t whenever applicable.  It sounds strict, but being very strict with types (and modifiers) is definiteley "c++"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of calling the member function `size()`, you can use C++20 [`std::ssize()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) to get the signed size for comparison and operation with signed integers.

```
std::vector v{42};
auto size = std::ssize(v); // get signed size
```